# await function didn't wait asynchronous anonymous function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, hapi.js

I tried using await to make my asynchronous function works like synchronous task, it works for regular function. But this doesn't work on my anonymous function.

So I have this function in my mongoose schema:

```js
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function comparePassword(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    cb(err, isMatch);
  });
};
```

I tried to validate my hashed password using `bcrypt.compare` which requires me to use anonymous function to get the result.

So I tried to compare password using this function:

```js
async (email, password, h) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({email: email, isDeleted: false})
    if (!user) {
        const data = ResponseMessage.error(400, User Not Found')
        return h.response(data).code(400)
    }
    await user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (isMatch) {
            console.log('TRUE')
            return h.response('TRUE')
        } else if (!isMatch) {
            console.log('FALSE')
            return h.response('FALSE')
        }
    })
    console.log('END OF FUNCTION')
    return h.response('DEFAULT')
}
```

Attachment:

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNCVW.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktutk.png)

I tried to run the server and comparing the password, but it gives me the result of DEFAULT. I tried debugging using console then it shows **TRUE/FALSE** is showing after **END OF FUNCTION**. So it prooves my function is working well but my await function didn't wait my task to run another line.

Any help for my this?

Comment: It's called a `callback-style` function, which is **not** a `Promise`, so you cannot use `await` here. You need to turn the `callback-style` function into a `Promise` if you want to utilize `async/await`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: you can add your images with preview, not as a link

Comment: @srknzl stackoverflow didn't allows me because I'm new user

Comment: check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to assign this to a Promise, like so:

```js
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async (candidatePassword, cb) => {
await new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    resolve(cb(err, isMatch));
  });

})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've supplied a callback to the compare function. The [bcrypt docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) say

> "Async methods that accept a callback, return a Promise when callback
> is not specified if Promise support is available."

Promise support is probably available, so try not returning a callback and it looks like it should work. :-)

If you come across later APIs which aren't Promise-aware, by the way, you might want to look at Node's [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function. It converts them to Promise-based functions. From the linked docs:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
const stats = await stat('.');
```